# Remove the Report a map error from google map

Tags: google-maps

I have a v3 google map and in the bottom-right corner of the map, there is a "Report a map error" link overlaid onto the map.  Does anyone know if it is possible to remove this from the map?

Edit: 
Here is an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ahfA5/

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you give a link to a map which demonstrates it? (The Google Maps site does it, but I can't make an API map do it)

Comment: It seems the message only appears over certain regions, for example (as of June 2012) if you zoom in on Melbourne Australia it will show, but not over Frankfurt Germany.

Comment: CrazyTim, thanks for posting an example

Answer (score 15):

You could style the map to get rid of this. [Check this out](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#creating_a_styledmaptype).

Notice that if you compare the first two screenshots, the "Report a map error" link is present in the first, but not in the second.

The simplest way to apply a dummy style to the map so that it still looks like google maps but without the error link would be to do the following:

```js
const styleOptions = {
  name: `Dummy Style`,
}

const MAP_STYLE = [
  {
    featureType: `road`,
    elementType: `all`,
    stylers: [{ visibility: `on` }],
  },
]
const mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(MAP_STYLE, styleOptions)
map.mapTypes.set(`Dummy Style`, mapType)
map.setMapTypeId(`Dummy Style`)
```

[Here's the updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwNyy/1).

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  This actually works and it complies with Google's TOS. Not a fan of the pessimistic non-answers above.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I tried it, and it's not even necessary to use any options for the dummy style. These three lines were enough: 
`var mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType();
map.mapTypes.set("Dummy Style", mapType);
map.setMapTypeId("Dummy Style");`

Comment: @CrazyTim, small favor...can you mark the answer as correct for the benefit of subsequent users? Thanks!!

Comment: It is a good solution, but not permanent.  When you change map type the link comes back...

Answer (score 5):

An issue with the custom style map is that when switching back from map/satellite or street view it does not return to the custom style instance.

```
// remove the wrapping container
.gm-style-cc:last-child {
    display: none !important;
}
// remove the link only
a[title="Report errors in the road map or imagery to Google"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the last CSS hack to remove the link only. I never knew you could do that with CSS (i.e tile="xyz")

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to disable this feature properly via the API.

Keep in mind, if you hide it without using the API it will violate the Google Maps API [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) which, as of the date of this post, doesn't allow developers to manipulate this link. Refer to 10.1.1.f.x:

> delete, obscure, or in any manner alter any brand features, logos, warnings, notices... or links that appear in the Service or the Content;

Answer (score 2):

The example presented here does works:

```
var styleOptions = {
        name: "Dummy Style"
    };

 var MAP_STYLE = [
    {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "all",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "on" }
        ]
    }
];
var mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(MAP_STYLE, styleOptions);
map.mapTypes.set("Dummy Style", mapType);
map.setMapTypeId("Dummy Style");
```

Initially the map get displayed WITHOUT the link on the Default map!

BUT

upon selecting either:

the MAP/Terrain or the SATELLITE/Label from the menu the Report map error link RETURNS on the map refresh.

If you choose as an alternative to create a StyledMapType MAP.

The Report a map error link can be disabled permanently on the StyledMap.

But you now have two MAPS (Default and the StyledMap).

I couldn't find a way to hide the default map.

Bottom line I couldn't remove the link Report a map error from the Default map permanently.

Comment: Seems like google have fixed the bug that made this workaround 'work'. No longer works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this - Google's attempt at providing accurate data via crowd-sourcing will cause this on occasion. Live with it and accept that limitation. you can layer a custom element on top of the canvas if you position it absolute or fixed. But that kind of violates their TOS as it also covers the copyright notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it using CSS trick. It's dirty but working:

```
/* remove ugly google report-a-bug button from maps */
.gmnoprint:last-child {
    display: none !important;
}
```